# maven Project proxy in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, proxy

I am working on Maven Project, while creating its throwing Error "Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archety" .Unable to download archtype.

It seems due to proxy issue its coming I have made the required changes using proxy and port no. in settings.xml. Still the error is same. Please help in this.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to add maven archetype catalog . Example http://howtodoinjava.com/tools/eclipse/how-to-import-maven-remote-archetype-catalogs-in-eclipse/